# using curl, shell scripting how to upload all the files in Specific path to host?

Tags: unix, curl, upload, host

i have written a script to upload all the files from a specific folder in local to the host, but there was some issue and the files are not getting uploaded to the host.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /main/folder_1/path/*
do
curl -u Pass:"Uname" -T  $i http://www.example.com/folder/path/$i
done
echo "*****File Uplodaed ******"
```

help me to solve this. the following is the error, that i got

```
<html>
<head>
<title> 500 Internal Server Error </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> 
Internal Server Error 
</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

currently i am having the script inside `/main/folder_2`, if i change `/main/folder_1/path/` to `../folder_1/path/`, i got the output as the files are moved. but i want to run the script with the complete path specified.

Comment: So what's the exact error and output you get? What's the return status of curl?

Comment: i am getting the error as the following <html><head><title>
500

Internal Server Error
</title></head><body><h1>
Internal Server Error
</h1>
</body></html>

Comment: currently i am having the script inside **/main/folder_2**, consider the above as  folder_1 **( " for i in /main/folder_1/path ")** . it gives the error, but if i change it to **../folder_1/path**, i got the output as the files got moved. i want to run the script with the complete path specified.

Comment: please amend your question with these comments. That will make an answer much easier :). However if you get 500 then the path as you specify triggers an error on the server.